# How to compare duration between two different TimeStamp

Tags: java

How to compare two timeStamp and get the difference from those. I am trying to get the duration between two different timeStamps. Using Date, But i am getting exception while comparing.

This how I get the timeStamp **01-08-2013 06:19:35**

I am getting exception like **java.text.ParseException: Unparseable
date: "01-08-2013 06:19:35"**

Comment: Post your code to see what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

Convert the date into milliseconds and then you can use

`long difference = finalDate.getTime() - initialDate.getTime();`

Regarding your `ParseException`, there is something wrong with parsing pattern for your date formatter. I think this is the correct one `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"` if you want to parse `"01-08-2013 06:19:35"`

## Joda-Time

Alternatively you can use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library and find the time difference in following way:

```
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
 DateTime finalDate = formatter.parse("someDate1");
 DateTime initialDate = formatter.parse("someDate2");
 Interval interval = new Interval(finalDate, initialDate);
```

Comment: The milliseconds approach is not the best way. Instead, just keep the Joda Time (not yoda time) approach.

Comment: You can use `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toXXX(difference)` to convert the delta in another unit.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yep. Sorry, star wars fan. :)

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski One catch with your sample code: **Time zones**. The strings will be parsed into date-time values using your JVM’s default time zone. That means Daylight Saving Time (DST) and other anomalies related to particular time zones affects your results. You should be adding a call to [`withZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone(org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)) and passing a [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) object. If strings are UTC/GMT, pass `DateTimeZone.UTC`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
  thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,25);
  thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH,7); // 0-11 so 1 less
  thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1985);

  Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(); //THIS IS TO GET TODAY DATE, you can simpy use your two dates

  long diff = today.getTimeInMillis() - thatDay.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
```

Here's an approximation...

```
long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

**PLUS** : To Parse the date from a string, you could use

```
  String strThatDay = "1985/08/25";
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
  Date d = null;
  try {
   d = formatter.parse(strThatDay);//catch exception
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } 


  Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
  thatDay.setTime(d); //rest is the same....
```

Comment: Your comparison method falls in the same problem as [Sajal Dutta's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18019271/1065197), check my comment.

Comment: Eugh, there is a `TimeUnit` class for this. Don't reinvent the wheel.